# If water is placed in an isothermal system, with the rest of it being vacuum, what would be the final pressure of the system?

Tags: thermodynamics

Given that a certain volume of water is placed in an isothermal system with the rest of it being vacuum, I believe the pressure would come from the vapor pressure of water at that temperature. My approach to this was by using the equation for work done in an isothermal process:

$$ W = nRT\ln\left(\frac{V_f}{V_i}\right) \tag{1} $$

Equating this to the latent heat of vaporization of the total mass of water present, but I couldn’t reach an answer that was viable.
To show my working:

\begin{equation}
    \pu{(536cal/g)}(10^5 \; \pu{g}) =
    (1 \cdot 10^5/18 \; \pu{mol}) (1.987) (303)
    \ln\left(\frac{V_f}{V_i}\right) \tag{2}
\end{equation}
where $V_i = 10^5 \; \pu{cc}$ as given in the problem.

On solving this my answer comes out to an absurdly large volume. And I am not sure that will help me find the right final pressure (for which I thought of using $P_\mathrm{i}V_\mathrm{i} = P_\mathrm{f}V_\mathrm{f}$ taking $P_\mathrm{i}$ as the vapor pressure of water at $\pu{303 K}$).

What’s wrong with my approach?

Comment: With any liquid water left, the final pressure depends only on temperature, raising with it roughly exponentially.

Comment: The final pressure is the vapor pressure of water at this temperature, which is $3167$ Pascal at $25$°C, and $101325$ Pascal at $100$°C. These values can be found in Tables. This is all to be done. The work has nothing to do here.

Comment: @Maurice in that case, given that initially the system is a vacuum, what would be the initial pressure? Since it needs to satisfy PiVi=PfVf

Comment: 1) There is no initial pressure, as the initial system is a vacuum.  2) The expression PV = constant is only valid when the amount of gas is constant. In the vacuum, the vacuum does not contain any gas. So pV is not constant, when introducing water in the system.

Comment: Is the system open or closed? As it is not explicitly stated. For the former is the result trivial, as the answer suggests. But I think vacuum was assumed as just initial state (plus water) of the closed system.

Comment: You can't do work expanding against a vacuum. You may want to quote the entire problem or cite the source.

Answer (score 1):

- Since it's isothermal, and the evaporating water removes heat, then heat energy is being supplied.
- Since it's *in vacuo*, all evaporated water is lost; i.e., the volume is considered *infinite*.
- At *any* temperature, *eventually* all the water will evaporate. The only question is how long it takes. At the cosmic background temperature, a ball of a few liters of ice would likely last a billion years, but at 303 K, in a few days, there would only be left the $\ce{H2O}$ adsorbed on the surface of the container.

  The volume of a gas is undefined *in vacuo*. Solids and liquids have defined volumes, not unconstrained gas.

Comment: Yep, you can't do work expanding against a vacuum. So the water would just go whoosh! Although evaporative cooling will lead it to freeze, so it might be  little less dramatic than that.

Answer (score -1):

What you are describing is physically incomprehensible. At 303K water has a vapor pressure P. If you place 5Kg of water in a container with a moveable piston applying enough force and adding enough heat to maintain 303K and pressure P eventually the water will all evaporate with a final volume V= nRT/P. Collect all the proper units and do the arithmetic. If the applied pressure is different from P a new equilibrium point[T] will be established or one of the phases will vanish.

Comment: This might be more appropriate as a comment (I did not downvote btw).

Comment: I am used to mysterious downvotes with no explanation. I tried to give a reasonable physical process to the questioner. The question unanswered is if work is done  in expanding vapor pressure against itself my moveable piston, opposed to placing the water in a vacuumjar of final volume V.

Comment: We are scratching our heads about an incomplete problem, methinks. Incomplete information. You'd have to provide either an external pressure or final volume. In the first case there would be work, not in the second.

Comment: 2 scenarios: I. Place water in evacuated container of volume V gas occupies at T and VP. add sufficient heat to evaporate liquid isothermally ideal gas Vi = 0 dE=0 dH= PV. 2. Place water in Container with piston of force equal to vapor pressure. add heat to vaporize liquid doing work against piston isothermal dE=0 = Q-W  Q=W dH = PV. Ideal gas law loses 5L of volume. E and H state functions. Each gives same value[Total dE = latent heat of vaporization]